# Trouble selecting a video from the gallery in Android 10/Q

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-gallery, android-10.0

I'm having trouble picking a video from the gallery in Android 10. I get the Uri from picking the video, but I'm not sure how to go about using that Uri in the onActivityResult with a contentProvider to retrieve the video that the user selected.

```
    fun loadVideoFromGallery(): Intent {
        return Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        ).apply {
            type = "video/*"
        }
    }
```

Here is the Uri I am getting in the onActivityResult (data?.data):

> content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F28/ORIGINAL/NONE/1128816056

I am able to cycle through the

> while (cursor.moveToNext())

and I am able to use the content that I am cycling through, but I can't figure out how to get to the video the user selected.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        val selectedVideoUri = date?.data
        if (selectedVideoUri != null) {
            val projection = arrayOf(
                        MediaStore.Video.Media._ID
                    )
            val selection: String? = null
            val selectionArgs: Array<String>? = null
            contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null
            )?.use { cursor ->
                try {
                    val idColumn =
                            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                        val contentUri: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id
                        )
                        val thumb = contentResolver.loadThumbnail(
                            contentUri, Size(imageView.width, imageView.height), null
                        )
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(thumb)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am looping through the elements inside the MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI directory, but the imageView.setImageBitmap(thumb) with always setup the last element it loops through.

I've been going through the documentation, but I still haven't found a way to resolve this is. Any help on how to interact with the content provider querying would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  imageView.setImageUri(data.getData());
```